# iframe Back with javascript - avoid main page go back

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm using an `iframe`, and I have a back button which runs this javascript code (when user clicks on back button):

```
document.getElementById("myframe").contentWindow.history.go(-1); // back
```

This works fine, but If there is no previous page in the frame, main page will go back.

How to avoid this? I want just iframe to go back, and if there is no previous page, simply do nothing.

EDIT: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/Brpj6/) is my code. (@ jsfiddle)

Comment: Maybe check iframes 'location.href' property? If it's default - do nothing.

Comment: @sleepwalker I haven't tested it, it seems to work fine. But... Isn't there any better way??

Comment: I'm not using complete address. (I'm using `../myfolder/a.html`), and even checking `iframe.src` didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean about checking `location.href`?? what is `location.href`?

Comment: document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.location.href  It will work only if you are on the same domain.

Answer (score 3):

Keep track of changes like this:

```
<script>
    window.iFrameChanges = -1; //will get incremented to 0 on first page load
</script>

<iframe onLoad="window.iFrameChanges+=1;" src="..."></iframe>
```

And the decrement the `window.iFrameChanges` value on history go back

This way you can know the "length" of history

Comment: This may not work, if user clicks on back button when page is not completely loaded... Any ideas?

Comment: The code that introduces the window.iFrameChanges should be above the back button that you added. If it is, then it will always be run before the user has a chance to use your back button. The only way I could see this occurring is if the script that introduces the variable is beneath the back button. Also make sure your javascript call on the back button isn't inline. Use a method. `<button onclick="goBack()">Back</button>` and the script `function goBack() { if (window.iFrameChanges > 0) { document.getElementById("myframe").contentWindow.history.go(-1); } }`

Comment: The problem is, you increase `iFrameChanges` on `onLoad`, means that it increases after new page is completely loaded. But if new page is loading, but still not completed, and user clicks on back button, then `iFrameChanges` won't increase...

Comment: I got an error if I try to access `history` property of the frame: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame Any solution to this? I mean there maybe some workaround to tell iframe to go back and forth without accessing `history`.