# Come back to iPad Webapp after going to Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad, web-applications

I'm creating an RSS Reader Web app for iPad. In my application, there is a button that opens the URL of each article in Mobile Safari (with `target="_blank"` method)

But the problem is, after user goes to Mobile Safari from my web app, and then closes Mobile Safari, iPad goes to the home page. but it should come back to my web app.

I tried to implement an in-app browser in my web app with `iframes`, but there is too much problems with it. many sites does not allow users to open their website inside an `iframe`, also there are some problems with implementing *back button* for the `iframe`, you can read the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602355/iframe-back-with-javascript-avoid-main-page-go-back).

What is the best way for my purpose? Is there any way to come back to web app after closing Mobile Safari? If not, what should I do? Is it possible to solve in-app browser problems? How?

Comment: Your use of the term "web app" confuses me; aren't "web apps" things that run in a browser?  Or are you talking about something like PhoneGap?

Comment: @Pointy I'm talking about apps that you can **pin** them to Home Screen and they can run in a chromeless browser, just like a native app.

Comment: Oh OK I know what you mean now.  Thanks for clarifying.  (In fact I decided not to make my own application be pinnable for pretty much this very reason :-)

Comment: What do you mean after closing safari? A user can either go to home screen or go to another app and that's completely her decision. You can't change anything there.

Comment: @keune User taps on a button, to read the complete article, and I'm opening Safari for him. And it's clear that he want to come back to application, because he didn't want to close my web app.

Comment: ok, if he wants to come back to your web app, he'll have open it again. This is the case for every application that fires safari to show a website.

Comment: @keune So maybe implementing an in-app browser is best way for me. But how to solve those problems? ...

Comment: This is a good question but OP needs to clarify what the question is about. I don't think it is clear to most people.

Comment: @NULL Can you help me in clarifying the question? I really don't know which part is not clear...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using phonegap (which it sounds like you are), I would suggest the [InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) or [ChildBrowser plugin](https://github.com/alunny/ChildBrowser/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: I don't use PhoneGap (See my comment to Pointy in the question). But please don't remove this answer, it might be useful for others who may visit this page later.

Comment: Sorry about that - I didn't see the comments (or maybe I was before them).  either way, I'll leave this in case it helps someone else :)